# Objective-C, rangeOfString from an offset

Tags: objective-c, search, nsstring

is it possible to use the method `rangeOfString` to search for a `NSString` starting from a given offset?

Something more similar to the `strpos` function in PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not `-rangeOfString:`, but a similar method - [`-rangeOfString:options:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:range:).

(**Edit**: An example)

```
NSString *string = @"YaddaYaddaYadda";
NSString *searchString = @"Yadda";
NSRange thisCharRange, searchCharRange;

searchCharRange = NSMakeRange(3, [string length]);
thisCharRange = [string rangeOfString:searchString options:0 range:searchCharRange];
NSLog(@"thisCharRange: %@", NSStringFromRange(thisCharRange));
```

Comment: @Marco, try [Searching, Comparing, and Sorting Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html)

Comment: searchCharRange = NSMakeRange(3, [string length] -3);  

This works better.

Answer (score 5):

#### I find a problem with the example up there. It'll cause "Range or index out of bounds".

```
searchCharRange = NSMakeRange(3, [string length]);
```

should change to

```
searchCharRange = NSMakeRange(3, [string length] - 3);
```

that is,the range's length should not be longer than the `original string's length - the range's start location`.

Comment: This is not really an answer. Edit the example, or comment on the post altogether.